# Setting Tesseract.js data location

Tags: typescript, adonis.js, tesseract.js

I built a server with Adonis.js and Typescript that downloads an image from the web and performs OCD on it with Tesseract.js. The program works, but every time a new Tesseract worker gets initialized this error shows up:
[image]

The eng.traineddata is being generated and stored in the root folder of the project, but Tesseract still can not find it for some reason. I also tried creating a "tessdata" folder in the root directory and setting the TESSDATA_PREFIX to its path, but that did not help either. Wondering if there is a simpler way to solve this issue.